# MX Record Status Connection Failed

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, exchange, mx-record

How to setup Windows Server MX Record then pointing to External Domain?
I try to configure like this but always getting error
[Windows Server MX Record Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrWu5.png) 
[Domain Hosting MX Record Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOmmb.png) 
[MX Record Lookup Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYBKJ.png)

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: my firewall is open this port for inbound and outbound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the IP address 180.241.131.83 is not reachable on port 25.
To pass the test, you may need to contact your ISP to ensure port 25 is open.

Comment: btw i was changed port to 587, is that problematic?, or i must open port 25 for this problem?

Comment: The MX record listens on port 25 by default. If it is not reachable,you may have trouble with receiving emails.

Comment: i see..., can i change MX record port manually?

Comment: No. As the MX record doesn't include a port. And the other mail servers will expect to connect to port 25.

Comment: okayyy, ty so much, i think this will solved this problem, but unfortunately my ISP is blocking port 25 for prevent spam email... :(